# Syntax highlightning with custom runtime path

Tags: syntax-highlighting

A server only has old versions of vim available in the repo, so I compile and run vim from my ~.

Starting vim it complains

```
line    2:
E484: Can't open file /usr/local/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
```

Where line 2 is where I have `syntax on`. This is obviously caused by the file not being present on the system.
Setting `let $VIMRUNTIME="/home/[user]/vim74/runtime/"` makes the error go away, however I still get no syntax highlightning what so ever.

I've checked that `/home/[user]/vim74/runtime/"` has a syntax directory containing hundreds of [language].vim files.

I've tried commenting out the rest of my settings to make sure I have nothing else interfering.

What am I missing?

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar  6 2015 15:34:54)
```

Comment: IIRC, to install on custom directory, when you `./configure`, you need to add `--prefix=/home/[user]`. Or maybe `--prefix=/home/[user]/vim74`.

Comment: Or try with `let $VIMRUNTIME="/home/[user]/vim74/"` (without `runtime` ending).

Comment: @tivn Naively I was trying to run with the runtime as it was in the _source_. I had never run make install (because I wanted to keep everything in ~). configure with a prefix and a make install did resolve the issue. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: ok, I will write as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile Vim source code and would like to install it on custom directory, this directory can be specified with `--prefix` option to the `./configure` command. Usually I will go as follows:

```
 ./configure --with-features=huge --prefix=$HOME/local
```

After this, proceed with `make` and then `make install`. This will install the Vim binaries under subdirectory `bin`, and also manual pages under subdirectory `share/man`. These path can then be added to your `PATH` and `MANPATH` respectively.

Alternatively, assuming Vim source code is extracted into `$HOME/vim74`, the `--prefix` and `make install` may be omitted, if you specify the following in your `.vimrc`. Please note that this is only based on experiment so it is not recommended -- something may break.

```
 let $VIM         = $HOME . "/vim74"    
 let $VIMRUNTIME  = $HOME . "/vim74/runtime"
 set runtimepath^=$VIMRUNTIME           
 set helpfile=$VIMRUNTIME/doc/help.txt  
 syntax on
```